# Moving TFS projects between TFS Collections with labels & history using TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, team-project, team-project-collection

I have a requirement of moving Team projects between two team project collections in TFS 2015. Also need the History & Label to be moved to the new collection.

I am aware there is no direct way of moving the project between collection along with history & label.

Can someone suggest a better way to handle it?

Thanks in Advance,
Dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already [a UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te) for this request, and this feature is under plan:

> We are committed to allow you to move team projects between
>   collections, although it’s currently not in scope for the 2016
>   calendar year. We’ll provide an updated timeline as we get closer to
>   2017.

An alternative, you can try with 3rd tools to move team projects, such as [TFS Integration Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe), [OpsHub](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2). Please read the limitations before using the tools.